# How to erase items which are values of map

Tags: c++, std

I have a map like this:

```
std::map<unsigned,(string,timestamp)> themap.
```

But I need to manage the size of the map by retaining only the highest 1000 timestamps in the map.  I am wondering what is the most efficient way to handle this?

Should I somehow make a copy of the map above into a

```
std::map<timestamp,(string,unsigned)> - erase elements not in top 1000, then massage this map back into original?
```

Or some other way?

Here is my code.

```
/* map of callid (a number) to a carid (a hex string) and a timestamp (just using unsigned here)
   The map will grow through time and potentially grow to some massive amount which would use up all 
   computer memory.  So max sixe of map can be kept to 1000 (safe to do so).  Want to remove items 
   based on timestamp
*/
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>


typedef unsigned callid;
typedef unsigned timestamp;
typedef std::string carid;
typedef std::pair<carid,timestamp> caridtime;
typedef std::map<callid,caridtime> callid2caridmap;

int main() {

   //map of callid -> (carid,timestamp)
   callid2caridmap cmap;

   //test data below
   const std::string startstring("4559023584c8");
   std::vector<carid> caridvec;
   caridvec.reserve(1000);
   for(int i = 1; i < 2001; ++i) {
      char buff[20] = {0};
      sprintf(buff, "%04u", i);
      std::string s(startstring);
      s += buff;
      caridvec.push_back(s);
   }
   //generate some made up callids
   std::vector<callid> tsvec;
   for(int i = 9999; i < 12000; ++i) {
      tsvec.push_back(i);
   }

   //populate map
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2000; ++i)
      cmap[tsvec[i]] = std::make_pair(caridvec[i], i+1);

   //expiry handling
   static const int MAXNUMBER = 1000;

   // what I want to do is retain top 1000 with highest timestamps and remove all other entries.  
   // But of course map is ordered by the key
   // what is best approach.  std::transform??
   // just iterate each one.  But then I don't know what my criteria for erasing is until I have
   // found the largest 1000 items
   // std::for_each(cmap.begin(), cmap.end(), cleaner);

   //nth_element seems appropriate.  Do I reverse the map and have key as timestamp, use nth_element 
   //to work out what part to erase, then un-reverse the map as before with 1000 elements
   //std::nth_element(coll.begin(), coll.begin()+MAXNUMBER, coll.end()); 
   //erase from coll.begin()+MAXNUMBER to coll.end()

   return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is a solution which I am playing with.

```
// as map is populated also fill queue with timestamp
std::deque<timestamp> tsq;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
   cmap[tsvec[i]] = std::make_pair(caridvec[i], i+1);
   tsq.push_back(tsvec[i]);
}
std::cout << "initial cmap size = " << cmap.size() << std::endl;


// expire old entries
static const int MAXNUMBER = 1000;
while(tsq.size() > MAXNUMBER) {
   callid2caridmap::iterator it = cmap.find(tsq.front());
   if(it != cmap.end())
      cmap.erase(it);

   tsq.pop_front();
}

std::cout << "cmap size now = " << cmap.size() << std::endl;
```

But still interested in any possible alternatives.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make a max-heap timestamp -> iterator to the object in the map.
The heap will be <= 1000 items.
check that when you insert in the heap you either have < 1000 items or the timestamp is < the max value of the heap and do the work in consequence when popping the item from the heap, if all this makes sense

Comment: I am looking up max-heap now.  How would I define the iterator given cmap above?

Comment: `cmap.find(callid)`. Check that it is != than cmap.end()

Comment: You can't use make_heap on a map.  Or maybe I don't understand your solution.

Comment: I don't know about make_heap. Im saying you should have a map and a heap.